# How to create 3 threads of parallel execution using boost library in C++ (in Visual Studio 2019)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, boost, boost-thread

I am trying to use the boost library to create 3 threads of execution, on Visual Studio 2019.
The 3 thread functions each has a while(1) loop, to keep executing continuously.

However, when I execute the program, I see that only the first thread is executed (and a breakpoint is hit).
So I understand that the first thread is getting created, and execution remains inside the first function's while(1) loop, the remaining 2 threads are not executed (breakpoints are NOT hit).

In such a case, how do I modify code, to get all 3 threads running?

Part of the code snippet used is below:

```
myfunction()
{
    // Some code here..

    boost::thread t(&myclass::kafkaSvc1ProducerThread, this, rk);
    t.join();

    boost::thread t2(&myclass::kafkaSvc2ProducerThread, this, rk);
    t2.join();

    boost::thread t3(&myclass::kafkaSvc3ProducerThread, this, rk);
    t3.join();

    // Some code here..
}

func1(1)
{
   while(1)
   { 
       // Some code here...
   }

}

void kafkaSvc1ProducerThread()
{
    func1();
}

func2(1)
{
   while(1)
   { 
       // Some code here...
   }

}

void kafkaSvc2ProducerThread()
{
    func2();
}

func3(1)
{
   while(1)
   { 
       // Some code here...
   }

}

void kafkaSvc3ProducerThread()
{
    func3();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just postpone joining the threads:

```
boost::thread t(&myclass::kafkaSvc1ProducerThread, this, rk);
boost::thread t2(&myclass::kafkaSvc2ProducerThread, this, rk);
boost::thread t3(&myclass::kafkaSvc3ProducerThread, this, rk);

t.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
```

Consider using a `thread_group`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! I postponed the join() to how you've suggested and it worked! Thanks again!